# ksh and a conditional list of function calls like fun1 && fun2

Tags: ksh

I completely got stuck with this

```
#!/bin/ksh

function one {
  echo one
  return 0
}

function two {
  echo two
  return 0
}

one && two
```

It prints

```
one
two
```

Why? I would expect two be never called because one returns 0 (`$? -eq 0` !)
What am I doing wrong?

I hope it is a banal mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regard to:

> I hope it is a banal mistake.

Sometimes, your hopes *do* come true :-)

Zero is a *successful* return code. If you want to indicate failure, you need to return a non-zero value.

For the `man` page for `ksh` (this is similar to `bash` and probably other shells as well), we see that:

> `cmd1 && cmd2` executes `cmd2` only if the exit status of `cmd1` is zero;

You can actually see this by running `true ; echo $?` - you should get a zero value.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It did not even dawned on me that this is about error code and true/false. Upped and accepted for you as a person. Well done. I just wished your nick was well done as well and not so much in error. Pax Christi.

Comment: @Grzegorz, in fairness, it's actually meant to be "at peace with *my* dark side", not "in league with the beast" :-)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Since you are at war - you want it or not - so I hope you are using the Devine helper. Blessings.